# connect the .js file having the knockout code to html page contained in Template folder

Tags: knockout.js

Here is my code

//Index.html that contain all the references...

```
<!-- Style Sheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/jquery.tablescroll.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/colorbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="baseCSS" media="screen" href="css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="mainCSS" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="loginCSS" media="screen" href="css/login.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="iframeCSS" media="screen" href="">

<!-- Framework & Library Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.tablescroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/sammy.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/plugins/sammy.template-latest.min.js"></script>  

<!-- Application -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

and here is my External Js file.

app.js reside in js folder in this i am writing the knockout code but its not working.

```
enter code here
```

this.get('#/setup/locations', function(context) {
        alert(sessionid);

```
        function ViewModelLocation()
        {
            var self = this;
            self.Id = ko.observable();
            self.Location = ko.observable();
            self.ParentLocation = ko.observable();
            var Location = 
            {
                Id:self.Id,
                Location: self.Location,
                ParentLocation:self.ParentLocation 
            };

            self.Location = ko.observable();
            self.Locations = ko.observableArray([]);
            $.ajax({
                    url:url+'Location/GetLocations?sessionkey='+sessionid + '&pageno='+1,
                    contenttype:'applicatiom/json;charset=utf-8',
                    data:{},
                    dataType:"text",
                    type:'GET',
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        var obj=JSON.parse(data);
                        if(obj.Status==400)
                        {

                            self.Location(obj.Values[0]);

                            alert(self.Location().Location);
                            self.Locations(obj.Values);
                            hideMobileMenu();
                            loadSetup(context,'locations', function() {
                            var tblHeight = $("section#main").height() - offsetHeight
                            $('table.grid').tableScroll({height:tblHeight});
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert(obj.Messages[0]);
                            loadSetup(context);

                        }

                    },
                    error:function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    if (jqXHR.status == 0) {
                        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                        alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                        alert('Time out error.');
                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                    } else {
                        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
            var viewmodel=new ViewModelLocation();
            ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);





    });
```

and thats my location page ...which is reside in Template folder.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:Locations"><tr class="odd"><td data-bind="text:Location"></td><td data-bind="text:ParentLocation"></td></tr></thbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

first check for syntax problems, like /thbody> or wrapping to whole thing in a table element. after that, when calling an observable you suppose to address a function in the ko object which returns the observable's value, so you need to use

```
    Id:self.Id(),
    Location: self.Location(),
    ParentLocation:self.ParentLocation ()
```

instead of what you did.
I assume that the )}; in the end closes the document.ready function, otherwise thats another problem.

**update**
this is an example code i wrote using yours, this one works. obviously, i couldnt debug your ajax call since i have no access to your server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- Style Sheets
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/jquery.tablescroll.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/colorbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="baseCSS" media="screen" href="css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="mainCSS" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="loginCSS" media="screen" href="css/login.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="iframeCSS" media="screen" href="">
    -->
<!-- Framework & Library Scripts -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.debug.js"></script>

<!-- Application -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ViewModelLocation() {
        var self = this;
        self.Id = ko.observable(1);
        self.Location = ko.observable("Ponyvill");
        self.ParentLocation = ko.observable("Aquestria");
        function Location()
        {
            this.Id= self.Id(),
            this.Location= self.Location(),
            this.ParentLocation= self.ParentLocation()
        };
        self.Locations = ko.observableArray([new Location()]);
       /* $.ajax({
            url: url + 'Location/GetLocations?sessionkey=' + sessionid + '&pageno=' + 1,
            contenttype: 'applicatiom/json;charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            dataType: "text",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                if (obj.Status == 400) {

                    self.Location(obj.Values[0]);

                    alert(self.Location().Location);
                    self.Locations(obj.Values);
                    hideMobileMenu();
                    loadSetup(context, 'locations', function () {
                        var tblHeight = $("section#main").height() - offsetHeight
                        $('table.grid').tableScroll({ height: tblHeight });
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert(obj.Messages[0]);
                    loadSetup(context);

                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                if (jqXHR.status == 0) {
                    alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            }
        });*/
    }
    var viewmodel = new ViewModelLocation();
    $(document).ready(function () {

        ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);


    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:Locations">
        <tr class="odd">
          <td data-bind="text:Location"></td>
          <td data-bind="text:ParentLocation"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still its not working...although in console no error is showing still I am not getting a proper out.have other suggestion.

Comment: You have written the knockout code in the same page that contain the <thbody data-bind="foreach:Locations"> but in my project the code is separated from the html page...if i kept my code in same page then it worked fine...but i don't want to do this...u have other solution

Comment: write it in a JS file and load it from your html like you load any js script, the result is the same.

Comment: yes..i know but the problem is, it is not working and i am unable to find the reason why its not working.I am getting an error ko not define even i added the reference file.

Comment: strange. what error did you get exatcly? i've tried loading the js from a script and it worked in my computer. the two relevant differences i see between our codes are the path and name of the knockout script and the version of the file, so these are the first things i would check if i were you. good luck